# How to setup Dapp on Cpanel?

Tags: truffle, dapps

I have followed the truffle petshop tutorial and it runs in my local machine, I have a shared hosting account and i would like to upload and test this Dapp on my server to start to modify it. The problem is that I don´t have idea how or what files upload to my server to run.

I have cpanel, shh access, node. In the run server do I have to change something?

Thanks a lot